# How to use cython to speed up scipy minimization when using a generated function?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I have a bit of code which follows the following essential pattern:

```
# matrices: list of matrices which represent approximations of orig
# orig: the original matrix
def gen_fxn(matrices, orig):
    def H(param):
        threshold(orig)
        sum = 0
        # iterate over all elements in all matrices to generate a sum from
        # the elementwise difference from orig (the original matrix)
        return sum
    return H
```

and then I use `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar` to minimize `H` within some specific bounds. Now, right now obviously the limiting factor is the speed of the function `H`. `matrices` is a long list (up to length 500) of large matrices (up to 100,000 x 100,000). I'd like to speed this up with cython somehow. I'm already using numpy. Can I do this? I tried reading introductory literature on using cython, but it's not clear on exactly how one could generate a function to then be used in other python code, because it seems to be the type definitions which speed up the performance, and there doesn't seem to be a "python function" type. I haven't even successfully gotten `minimize_scalar` to complete on a high-performance compute cluster... (been running for about 30 minutes now with `maxiter=100`, `'brent'` solver). Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The inside of `def` functions are still compiled by Cython and can still be sped-up. You typically want to ensure the variables they use are typed. With that said, this sounds like a problem where plain numpy code should be pretty efficient so you might not gain a lot from Cython. It might help to show how you're doing this currently.

Comment: A list of 500 elements each containing a matrix of size `100,000 x 100,000` with double precision requires at least `37` tera-byte of memory. Are you sure about this? If memory wasn't an issue, you could perform the sum of differences pretty efficiently using vectorised numpy, which would be as good/fast as cython.

Comment: @romeric Yes. Right now the test data I'm working on is only about 1,500 x 1,500 (500 elements), but potentially the code will be used on matrices of that size. I presume for these cases virtual memory will be used. Also, when used on larger datasets, sparsity might be induced somehow.

Comment: @DavidW I will check and make sure I can share my current code, and then I will. Thanks for your reply, that's actually what I suspected. Could you recommend somewhere to read about the optimizations np does in the background?

Comment: Numpy is quick if you're doing operations on whole arrays at once (rather than iterating element-by-element in your Python code). If your code looks something like `(a-orig).sum()` then the chances are it's pretty quick and you probably won't beat it significantly in Cython. The two places something like that could be improved are avoiding allocating temporary arrays and parallelizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice in the comments I used the following approach. Rather than iterate over the elements, which is slow, I used a mask to remove the elements I need (I only wanted to sum over elements above the diagonal -
 `i < j`) within the matrices, performed the subtraction, elementwise multiplication, squaring, and in-matrix summing using `np` fxns. Improved speeds by a factor of 8-10 over the double-for loop approach with N = 5000 or so.